# Wi-Fi performance: 40MHz channel width vs. 20MHz channel width

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there any reason to utilize 40MHz-wide channels on the 5GHz radio versus 20MHz-wide channels?

Background:
I admin an enterprise Wi-Fi network with 11,000+ APs. The 5GHz radio is currently using 40MHz channel width.  What is the benefit of this vs. using 20MHz channel width?

Answer (score 3):

Doubling the channel width slightly more than doubles the speeds of the PHY rates you can get.

With 20MHz-wide channels on 802.11n, you can only get the 72.2, 144.4, or 216.6Mbps top PHY rates (for 1-, 2-, and 3 spatial streams, respectively). Going to 40MHz-wide channels makes it 150, 300, and 450 Mbps, respectively.

Of course this also cuts your available channels in half, so some enterprise Wi-Fi deployments choose to keep the narrow channels in order to crowd in more APs.

40- (and 80-) MHz-wide channels are fine in the spacious 5GHz band. But 40MHz-wide channels can cause problems in the relatively narrow 2.4GHz band, where 40MHz wide channels take up half the band and don't leave enough room for Bluetooth and other 2.4GHz technologies to work well.

Comment: In the 5GHz band, you've got 28 available 20 MHz channels in the US, but only 13 of the 40 MHz channels to choose from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)

Comment: Just to understand, clarify and conclude as a non-networking savvy reader, does this mean the 40 MHz option might be better for higher internet speed and a smaller pool of devices (in doing so might affect stability to Bluetooth connected devices as well) where 20 Mhz allows for a broader but slower connection?

Comment: @Barrosy If you have any devices that use Bluetooth, or any other non-Wi-Fi devices that use the 2.4GHz band (game controllers, cordless phones, baby monitors, wireless subwoofers/surround speakers), or can see any networks from your neighbors, you should use 20MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz. 2.4GHz is now a garbage legacy band where you stick crappy things that don't need great performance. If you want performance, use 6GHz (Wi-Fi 6E) which is new and uncrowded for now, or maybe 5GHz, which is becoming increasingly crowded but isn't as bad as 2.4GHz.